# Assigning output to variable in automated chroot script

Tags: bash, chroot

For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to chroot through a script, and assign a value to a variable. Okay, so I learned how to chroot and execute commands from a script without halting the flow of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Mini script for chrooting into chroot_dir and executing commands.

chroot_dir=$1
cat << EOF | chroot $chroot_dir /bin/bash
sysname=\`hostname\`
echo "You are running script.sh on ${sysname}"
EOF
```

Running this script, `./script.sh "/chroot_dir/"`, I get the following output:

> You are running script.sh on

It seems like either sysname never gets assigned, or sysname loses its value immediately. How do I assign a value to sysname using this method to chroot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `${sysname}` gets evaluated when the script is read, rather than when later executed. If you put a backslash (`\`) before the dollar (`$`) it should work better.
Note that it has nothing to do with `chroot`, but it rather is a feature of `bash`.

Comment: Whoa! I totally forgot about that... Thanks!